# Error installing scrapy. Microsft Visual Studio is also installed

Tags: python, visual-studio, scrapy, pipenv

I am trying to install `scrapy` using `pipenv`.
Earlier there was another error and by searching I found `Visual Studio` will solve the issue. I installed and followed that guide but it didnt resolve my issue entirely. I am getting a different error now.

When I run `pipenv install scrapy`

```
  fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'libxml/xpath.h': No such file or directory
  error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.29.30133\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
  *********************************************************************************
  Could not find function xmlCheckVersion in library libxml2. Is libxml2 installed?
  *********************************************************************************
```

I know there are many questions related to this but none are solving my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar error code when trying to install lxml despite having Visual Studio 2019 installed.
Changing back to Python Interpreter 3.8 solved problem for me.